# Javascript moving things

Tags: javascript, image, move

I  am trying to move an img from right to left

however the code only works from left to right

this is an example of the left to right one this one works

```
 <script language="javascript">
 var x = 310; //Starting Location - left

 var dest_x = 300;  //Ending Location - left

 var interval = 2; //Move 10px every initialization

 function moveImage() {
//Keep on moving the image till the target is achieved
if(x<dest_x) x = x + interval; 


//Move the image to the new location

document.getElementById("ufo").style.left = x+'px';

if ((x+interval < dest_x)) {
    //Keep on calling this function every 100 microsecond 
    //  till the target location is reached
    window.setTimeout('moveImage()',10);
}
```

does someone know the problem ? would really really appreciate it !

Comment: try making either interval negative, or taking it away from x not adding.  your currently starting at 310 and adding 2 every loop so you wont get down to 300

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine the problem stems from using `document.getElementById("ufo").style.left` if you are moving right to left have you tried changing this value to `document.getElementById("ufo").style.right`?

Answer (score 0):

The left attribute defines a distance from the left side. You are increasing the left value, so naturally this would cause it to move from left to right. You can have it move from right to left by decreasing the attribute. Basically, just set interval to -2. Also, you should change if (x < dest_x) to be if (x > dest_y), otherwise it will never run.

Walk through it:
You begin at 310 pixels from the left side, and set the distance you travel each iteration to +2.
You check to see if 312 is less than 300 (your destination); it is not.
If it were, then you would change the x value to 310 + 2 = 312; you would now be 312 pixels from the left side.
You then check to see if x + distance (312) is less than 300 before repeating the loop.

Comment: I tried what you said but it still isn't moving :(       

       var x = 310; //Starting Location - top
       var dest_x = 300;  //Ending Location - top
       var interval = -2; //Move 2px every initialization

         function moveMenu() {
 //Keep on moving the image till the target is achieved
 if(x>dest_y) x = x + interval;
 
 //Move the image to the new location
 document.getElementById("menu").style.top  = x+'px';

 if ((x+interval < dest_x)) {
  //Keep on calling this function every 100 microsecond 
  // till the target location is reached
  window.setTimeout('moveMenu()',10);
 }
}

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit late replying, had to go do something after making this reply. You need to change the second part where it says if ((x+interval < dest_x)) to also be greater than, or else it won't loop, and you may as well take out the outer parenthesis while you're at it. So make it if (x + interval > dest_x)